# A message broker that supports updating message metadata?

Tags: metadata, messagebroker, service-broker

I am looking for a message broker that allows message consumers to update the message metadata by adding a field and value, which is stored in the broker, after they have received the message and before they acknowledge complete consumption to the broker. Are you aware of any broker with this feature?

This is for implementing deterministic cleanup logic of generated side effect garbage due to message processing failures and retries. For more elaboration of the use case you can refer to:

[Token-based deduplication](https://exactly-once.github.io/posts/token-based-deduplication/)
[Side effects in message processing](https://exactly-once.github.io/posts/side-effects/)

Many thanks.